# Two remotes in one repository

Tags: git, gerrit

I have two repositories - one is origin and there lies application which is developed by other team and second repo is local, created by me, for my team - currently it's empty. So creating this is the easiest part:

```
git remote add origin <origin url>
git remote add local <local url>
```

What i would like to achieve is to be able to download all commits from specific branch in origin repo, do some changes to it and upload all commits from origin with my changes as new commit to local repo - i need to save history from origin repo and add my changes at the top. Later of course i would like to fetch origin and again add some changes and so on. My main problem is to connect these two repos. Any ideas how to achieve it?

I use Git with Gerrit revision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one repository at `<origin url>` and another repository at `<local url>`.

You have a single local repository, on which you added two remotes, origin and local. (Maybe use a more meaningful name than "local".)

You can fetch all commits from origin by doing `git fetch origin`. - Now `git branch -r` should list all branches on origin prefixed with `remotes/origin`.

Now you can checkout a branch `git checkout -b master origin/master` which creates a local master branch. You can do your commits and afterwards push everything to your `local` remote: `git push local master:master`. This will push your local master to a remote branch called master, too.

In your situation `git branch -a` should list local branches (without prefix) and remote branches for `origin` and `local`.

Just fetch changes from one remote do your commits and push it to the other remote.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are only going to do this with Gerrit you may want to check out the Python package git-review https://pypi.python.org/pypi/git-review. I haven't tried it yet, but it adds commadns to git so that when you do "git review " instead of pushing to origin you send to the gerrit repo (default name 'gerrit').

If you don't want to get fancy though michas solution is correct. However, as he mentioned you should probablt rename your local repo to 'gerrit' so its purpose is more obvious.